# How to improve this Merge Sort?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I have written a mergesort in Python/Numba:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.jit( nopython=True )
def merge( x ):

    n = x.shape[0]
    width=1

    r   = x.copy()
    tgt = np.empty_like( r )
    while width<n:
        i=0
        while i<n:
            istart = i
            imid = i+width
            iend = imid+width
            # i has become i+2*width
            i = iend

            if imid>n:
                imid = n

            if iend>n:
                iend=n
            _merge( r, tgt, istart, imid, iend)

        # Swap them round, so that the partially sorted tgt becomes the result,
        # and the result becomes a new target buffer
        r, tgt = tgt, r
        width*=2

    return r

@nb.jit( nopython=True )
def _merge( src_arr, tgt_arr, istart, imid, iend ):
    """ The merge part of the merge sort """
    i0   = istart
    i1   = imid
    for ipos in range( istart, iend ):
        if ( i0<imid ) and ( ( i1==iend ) or ( src_arr[ i0 ] < src_arr[ i1 ] ) ):
            tgt_arr[ ipos ] = src_arr[ i0 ]
            i0+=1
        else:
            tgt_arr[ ipos ] = src_arr[ i1 ]
            i1+=1
```

I have written a test for it:

```
def test_merge_multi(self):

    n0 = 21
    n1 = 100

    for n in range( n0, n1 ):
        x = np.random.random_integers( 0, n, size=n )

        with Timer( 'nb' ) as t0:
            r = sas.merge( x )
        with Timer( 'np' ) as t1:
            e = np.sort( x, kind='merge' )
        #print( 'r:%s'%str(r))
        #print( 'e:%s'%str(e))
        print( 'nb/np performance %s'%(t0.interval/t1.interval ))
        np.testing.assert_equal( e, r )
```

I used this Timer class:

```
import time

class Timer:    

    def __init__(self,title=None):
        self.title=title

    def __enter__(self):
        if self.title:
            print( 'Beginning {0}'.format( self.title ) )
        self.start = time.clock()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.end = time.clock()
        self.interval = self.end - self.start
        if self.title:
            print( '{1} took {0:0.4f} seconds'.format( self.interval, self.title ) )
        else:
            pass#
            #print( 'Timer took {0:0.4f} seconds'.format( self.interval ) )
```

The test results are:

```
nb/np performance 9307.846153856719
nb/np performance 1.1428571428616743
nb/np performance 0.7142857142925115
nb/np performance 0.8333333333302494
nb/np performance 0.9999999999814962
nb/np performance 0.9999999999777955
nb/np performance 0.8333333333456692
nb/np performance 0.8333333333302494
nb/np performance 1.0
nb/np performance 0.8333333333456692
nb/np performance 1.0
nb/np performance 1.0
nb/np performance 1.0
nb/np performance 0.8333333333456692
nb/np performance 0.9999999999814962
nb/np performance 1.0
nb/np performance 0.9999999999814962
nb/np performance 1.0
nb/np performance 1.0
nb/np performance 1.0000000000185036
nb/np performance 1.2000000000044408
nb/np performance 1.0
nb/np performance 1.0
nb/np performance 1.0
nb/np performance 1.0000000000185036
nb/np performance 1.2000000000088817
nb/np performance 1.0
nb/np performance 1.1666666666512469
nb/np performance 1.0
nb/np performance 1.0
nb/np performance 0.9999999999814962
nb/np performance 1.1666666666728345
nb/np performance 1.1666666666512469
nb/np performance 1.0
nb/np performance 1.0
nb/np performance 1.1666666666512469
nb/np performance 1.1666666666512469
nb/np performance 1.1666666666728345
nb/np performance 1.1666666666728345
nb/np performance 1.1666666666728345
nb/np performance 1.1666666666728345
nb/np performance 1.1666666666512469
nb/np performance 1.1666666666512469
nb/np performance 1.0
nb/np performance 1.1666666666728345
nb/np performance 1.3333333333456692
nb/np performance 1.3333333333024937
nb/np performance 1.3333333333456692
nb/np performance 1.1428571428435483
nb/np performance 1.3333333333209976
nb/np performance 1.1666666666728345
nb/np performance 1.3333333333456692
nb/np performance 1.3333333333209976
nb/np performance 1.000000000012336
nb/np performance 1.1428571428616743
nb/np performance 1.3333333333456692
nb/np performance 1.3333333333209976
nb/np performance 1.1428571428616743
nb/np performance 1.1428571428616743
nb/np performance 1.3333333333456692
nb/np performance 1.499999999990748
nb/np performance 1.2857142857074884
nb/np performance 1.2857142857233488
nb/np performance 1.2857142857029569
nb/np performance 1.1428571428616743
nb/np performance 1.1428571428435483
nb/np performance 1.2857142857233488
nb/np performance 1.2857142857233488
nb/np performance 1.2857142857233488
nb/np performance 1.2857142857233488
nb/np performance 1.2857142857233488
nb/np performance 1.2857142857029569
nb/np performance 1.1249999999895917
nb/np performance 1.2857142857029569
nb/np performance 1.2857142857233488
nb/np performance 1.4285714285623656
nb/np performance 1.249999999993061
nb/np performance 1.1250000000034694
nb/np performance 1.2857142857029569
```

graphed results (from a different run):

[image]

Graphed results from a longer run:

[image]

Please note that for n<=20, numpy uses an insertion sort when the mergesort is called: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/npysort/mergesort.c.src

So you can see that for small values of n, the numba version of the mergesort beats the numpy version.

However, as n gets larger, numpy then consistently outperforms numba by a factor of 2.

Why is this? And how could I optimise the numba version to beat the numpy version for all n?

Comment: You might like to ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Why do you assume that numba *ought* to be able to beat numpy for all *n*? numpy's merge sort was implemented in C by some pretty smart people, and whilst numba has some impressive self-optimizing capabilities, it's not a magic bullet. Well-written C code can definitely beat numba in some circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

If your purpose in life is to beat numpy's implementation, you might as well try to more closely reproduce what's being done there. There are two main differences algorithmically from what you have implemented:

- NumPy implements recursion top-down, by actual recursion. You are using a bottom's up approach, which spares you the recursion stack, but typically ends up producing unbalanced merges, which reduce efficiency.
- While your ping pong buffers approach is a neat one, you are moving more data around than is strictly necessary. Doing the sort in-place, like NumPy does, will reduce the size of the total memory you need to access to at least 75% of your implementation's, which will probably help with cache performance as well.

Leaving aside the Numba magic, this is a pretty close match to the internal workings of NumPy's mergesort:

```
def _mergesort(x, lo, hi, buffer):
    if hi - lo <= 1:
        return
    # Python ints don't overflow, so we could do mid = (hi + lo) // 2
    mid = lo + (hi - lo) // 2
    _mergesort(x, lo, mid, buffer)
    _mergesort(x, mid, hi, buffer)
    buffer[:mid-lo] = x[lo:mid]
    read_left = 0
    read_right = mid
    write = lo
    while read_left < mid - lo and read_right < hi:
        if x[read_right] < buffer[read_left]:
            x[write] = x[read_right]
            read_right += 1
        else:
            x[write] = buffer[read_left]
            read_left += 1
        write += 1
    # bulk copy of left over entries from left subarray
    x[write:read_right] = buffer[read_left:mid-lo]
    # Left over entries in the right subarray are already in-place

def mergesort(x):
    # Copy input array and flatten it
    x = np.array(x, copy=True).ravel()
    n = x.size
    _mergesort(x, 0, n, np.empty(shape=(n//2,), dtype=x.dtype))
    return x
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will play around with your code. Why does the bottom up search produce unbalanced merges? I have tried Googling but without success.

Comment: If you array is 12 items long, the last merge will be of an 8 item one with 4 item one, instead of the 6 and 6 of the top down approach.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now!

Comment: Unfortunately, numba can't do recursive calls, so I can't try out your suggestion with numba.;{

Comment: We could rewrite it to store indices in a list used as a stack, not sure if the list will trip Numba because of it making Python API calls. Will take a look at it tonight.